# Chrome not following @media print rule in few scenarios

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

In my style sheet i am using @media print rule but in few scenarios specially regarding links it is not getting the link color which is defined but instead it gets the default link color which is on page and this problem is only and only on google chrome but rest of the styling is working.

I followed few of the suggestion given on other issues regarding media print css but it didn't helped as well.

following methods i already have used

```
<style media="print"></style>

@media print{
    a:link{color:balck !important;}
}

<link rel"" type"text/css" media="print" src="print.css" />
```

so i would like to know what i am missing here and what else i can try ??

Comment: A demo or the live site would help. Seems like the problem is in your CSS, you may have used !important already or something like that. BTW, I hope that `balck` was just a typo and it's not like that in your real CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @media print, you need to add !important in your styles, or the page will use the element's inline styles that have higher priority.

E.g.

```
<div class="myelement1" style="display:block;">My div already has inline styles.</div>
```

In @media print

```
@media print {
   .myelement1, .myelement2 { display: none !important; }
}
```